# How To Unit Test .NET Backend

Tags: unit-testing, azure-mobile-services

can someone give me hints, how to unit test the .NET backend in a good way? I have tried http://blog.mdavies.net/2014/04/28/creating-and-integration-testing-a-dot-net-c-sharp-backend-for-azure-mobile-services/ but that way I have all parts of the framework in my unit test. Including the complete DB. I found it hard to seperate controllers and DB in Unit tests. How can I do this? Does anybody unit test the backend in .NET?

Kind regards,

Markus

Comment: Can you show us some of your controller code?

Comment: What I want to do is something like: `var result = controller.GetAllTodoItems(); Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count);` but not on client side through an HTTP call. Just an as easy as possible unit test.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly do not want to test the actual service and the actual database when unit testing. Here are three articles that will get you started on unit testing your .NET backend.

1. [Unit Testing ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-with-aspnet-web-api)
2. [Mocking Entity Framework when Unit Testing ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/mocking-entity-framework-when-unit-testing-aspnet-web-api-2)
3. [Walkthrough: Using TDD with ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff847525(v=vs.100).aspx)